# TenantId is null when saving an entity in a Discriminator based multi tenant application in Grails 3.2 with GORM 6

Tags: grails-orm, grails-3.2.0.m2

I am trying to implement a MultiTenant application using GORM 6.0.0.RC2.
When a domain class that implements MultiTenant is saved via the GORM's save() method, the tenantId property is not set to the current tenantId. It is always null and hence fails validation. However Tenants.currentId() returns the correct tenant id based on the specified tenant resolver class.

Is it the application's responsibility to set the tenantId on an instance of the domain class when it is saved or will GORM take care of it by setting the property appropriately before being saved?

My Domain Person class

```
class Person implements MultiTenant<Person> {
  String id
  String tenantId
  String name
}
```

and the code to save an instance of the Person class is

```
new Person(name: "pmohan").save(failOnError: true)
```

it always fails with a validation exception indicating tenantId is null.
But the tenant resolver according to the configuration below resolves to the right tenantId.

```
gorm:
    multiTenancy:
        mode: DISCRIMINATOR
        tenantResolverClass: com.MyTenantResolver
```

Also the Tenants.currentId returns the value as expected. I was expecting the save() method to populate the tenantId property automatically based on MyTenantResolver class.

Comment: can you post your domain code and the code you are using to save the domain instance?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with GORM 6.0.9, any updates?